# Why does this simplest jQuery hide element in iframe code doesn't work even on the same origin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to hide an element in iframe (same origin), but no luck. Trying it here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_script

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#iframeID").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});

    $('#iframeID').on('load', function()
    {
        console.log($('#iframeID').contents().find('#mySidenav'));
        $('#iframeID').contents().find('#mySidenav').hide();
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<iframe id="iframeID" height="800px" width="800px"  src="https://www.w3schools.com/" ></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

The sidebar just doesn't hide, what is wrong? Here is the element on that website I am trying to hide:

```
<nav class="w3-sidebar w3-collapse w3-white w3-card-2" id="mySidenav">
```

Comment: Unless your domain is `https://www.w3schools.com` that `<iframe>` has contents from a different origin.

Comment: No, I am testing on that link I gave, so it runs completely on the same domain

Comment: Ah. Well I think the problem is that that element (the `<nav>`) has a style in a CSS stylesheet with `display: block !important;`, and that overrides the local `display: none` that `.hide()` uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it's because of some HTML on the page.  When I used remove() it worked properly.  Most likely somewhere there is `display: block !important` in the CSS.

```
html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
        $("#iframeID").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});

        $('#iframeID').on('load', function()
        {
                console.log($('#iframeID').contents().find('#mySidenav').remove());
        });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<iframe id="iframeID" height="800px" width="800px"  src="https://www.w3schools.com/" ></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's some CSS; something is giving it `display: block !important`

Comment: @Pointy how would I fix that?  But I did update the explanation.

Comment: No no I was just clarifying. The only way I know of to override that CSS rule would be to alter the stylesheet, which would be possible but I don't know why one would go to the trouble for just an exercise. Your answer is fine ;)

Comment: @nfnneil thanks man, here is another question :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822030/how-to-detect-when-iframe-starts-loading-another-page