# How to detect when iframe starts loading another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to hide an element in same-origin iframe. However, this son of a bi*ch blinks for a few ms before getting hidden. So what I did was added `display: none` and remove it after iframe is loaded - great. But now, when user clicks inner page link of iframe, which also contains element to be hidden, it still blinks (because `display:none` is now removed). I need to detect when to add it again, i. e. just before another page starts to load.

**Testing here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_script**

Here is what I tried:

```
<html class="js">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
html.js #iframeID
{
    display: none;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#iframeID').on('load', function()
    {
        $('#iframeID').contents().find('a').on('click', function()
        {
            $('html').addClass('js');
            console.log('click');
        });
        console.log('loaded');
        $('#iframeID').contents().find('#mySidenav').remove();
        $('html').removeClass('js');


    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<iframe id="iframeID" height="800px" width="800px"  src="https://www.w3schools.com/" ></iframe>
<script>

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

However, there are some `a` elements that don't load another page. In this example, try clicking on "TUTORIALS" at the top of that iframed webpage - it just opens up dropdown, not loads another page.

What should I do?

I noticed that "TUTORIALS" link has `href="javascript:void(0)"`. Maybe I should be somehow selecting all `a` links without such href? But not sure if it's fool proof.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.iFrame_class').load(function(){
        console.log('frame loaded');
    });
});
```

Alternatively on start load solution:

Custom attribute for iframe:

```
iframe class="iFrame" src="some site" started="0"
```

Put this code to iframed page:

```
  window.parent.$('.iFrame').attr("started","0"); //makes iframe started attr to false on page load
  $(document.body).on("click","a", function() {
     window.parent.$('.iFrame').attr("started","1");// makes iframe started attr to true for all clicked links
  });
```

And listen; is started attribute changed to 1 on parent page?

Comment: no, this gets called AFTER the iframe is loaded, I need one before it starts loading...

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `load` event on the `iframe` as such,

```
$('iframe').on('load', function(){
    console.log('Iframe Loaded');
});
```

The `iframe`'s load event is also called every time it's src changes.

Comment: no, this gets called AFTER the iframe is loaded, I need one before it starts loading...

Comment: @Gintas_ How are you changing the content of the `iframe`. Is it through a click . If so please post the relevant code.

Comment: well, the iframed webpage contains simple a href links to other pages

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the damn blinking by making 2 iframes and showing 2nd while 1st one is loading. While 1st one is loading, it's also hidden, becomes unhidden after it finishes loading. Anyway, here is my code, should help someone:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
iframe.js
{
    display: none;
}
iframe.unclickable
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#iframeID1').on('load', function()
    {
    $('#iframeID1').contents().find('a[href!="javascript:void(0)"]').filter('a[target!="_blank"]').filter('a[target!="_top"]').filter('a[target!="_parent"]').on('click', function()
        {
            $('#iframeID1').addClass('js');
            $('#iframeID2').removeClass('js');
        });
        $('#iframeID1').contents().find('#mySidenav').remove();
        $('#iframeID1').removeClass('js');
        $('#iframeID2').addClass('js');
        $('#iframeID2').contents().find('html').html($('#iframeID1').contents().find('html').html());

    });


});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<iframe id="iframeID1" height="800px" width="800px"  src="https://www.w3schools.com/" class="js"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframeID2" height="800px" width="800px" src="https://www.w3schools.com/" class="js unclickable" ></iframe>
<script>

</script>
</body>

</html>
```